# LWUIT: Layout calculation problem

Tags: java, java-me, mobile, lwuit

I have a rather large application written with LWUIT. With only a few screens that have the problem.

**The problem:**

When the page loads, everything looks fine. but when you scroll you can't scroll to the bottom, and when you click on a list it selects the item below where you clicked and not on where you clicked

However, when you click a select the list for a second time, all is fine. Also when a dialog pops up, after clicking it away, all is fine. And when I forget to call show() or repaint() he does not paint anything but when i try to scroll he shows() everything and he calculates it correctly.

I'm really puzzled about this problem. I'm searching on it for a long time now. And I would love to gain some new insights here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After 5 days of searching on it, I finally found the solution. You have to call form.show() after you have added everything to your form. and not before, like I was doing.

Most of the time it works fine in both ways. Just not always.